# deck of cards nullpointerexception

Tags: nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a blackjack game and ive made a Card class and Deck class so far. I am trying to test my classes to make sure everything is working by printing out the deck in a string but when i run the program its giving me a null pointer exception and telling me the problem is when i try to add a card to my array list of cards

This is the code thats giving me problems

```
{
    deckSize = decks * CARDS_IN_DECK;
    // Add cards to deck
    for (int deck = 0; deck < decks; deck++)
    {
        for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
        {
            for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++)
            {
                cards.add(new Card(suit, value)); //error occurs here
            }
        }
    }

    // Shuffle cards
    if (shuffle)
    {
        this.shuffle();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the language?  How was `cards` declared/initialized?  What is the point of `deckSize`?

Comment: I assume `cards` is a list. Do you initialize it? If yes: where?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is really on that line, you forgot to allocate memory for `cards` using `new`.

That means that if the data type for `cards` is `ArrayList`, you should do:

```
ArrayList cards = new ArrayList();
```

before any method of `cards` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You just have declared your list but forgot to initialize the cards list.

Initialize cards as below before adding any elements to it:

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
```